# Server Error in '/' Application. Configuration Error ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am facing a error in the browser when i am running my website from MS Visual Studio.I want to work on default.aspx page. I am beginner a ASP.net developer.
Screenshot attached.
web.config code attached.
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-goTestSite-20161022093915.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-goTestSite-20161022093915;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 Line 14:     </connectionStrings>
 Line 15:      <system.web>
 Line 16:        <authentication mode="None" />
 Line 17:        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
 Line 18:       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
          </providers>
        </sessionState>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

the error shows red in line 16.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Hope that below answer helped your problem

Answer (score 1):

The above error can cause for many reason , but i think one solution for your problem is , just set the default.aspx page as your start page by right click that page and run your application.

hope that will solve your problem otherwise we look for other solution , kindly let me know your thoughts or feedback.

Detailed solution here: http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/02/17/163375.aspx

thanks
karthik